# Email Id from Facebook Sdk in xamarin android

Tags: android, facebook, xamarin

```
   LoginManager.Instance.LogInWithReadPermissions(this,new List<string>{"public_profile","user_friends","email"});

void MProfileTracker_mOnProfileChanged (object sender, OnProfileChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        string ProfilePic_URL;
        if (e.mProfile != null) {

            string FullName;
            string ID;

            FullName = e.mProfile.Name;
            ID = e.mProfile.Id;
        }
```

How to get email-id of facebook using facebook-sdk 4.5.1.0 ? I have tried above code but in ID I am getting some number like 95656412588855.

Comment: If by "Email ID" you mean "Email Address", you need to read out the email address, which - it seems - you are not doing in the provided code snippet. Please edit the question and add some code that shows how you are reading the email address